# PHP JSON and Android

Tags: php, android, html, json

Right now in my class we are building an android app for my school. This class does not have a actual meeting time so some of the people in my class I have not talked to face to face. One of these individuals has been programming the json and php for different feeds. The problem is that he has sent me a php file and I am not entirely sure how to parse the information in it to be able to display the feed on the app.

I am fairly proficient in Java and XML, not so much in PHP(I am taking it now) or JSON(used it once about a year ago)

So I have 3 questions

1.what does my app need to send the page to be able to access the different feeds?

2.Where should the database reside?

3.What way should I parse the info that is sent to me from this page.

FYI the App is just a basic design right now so there is no classes or anything to worry about.

Here is the PHP file

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$user_name = "web";
$password = "internet";
$db_name = "cptc";

@$db = mysqli_connect($server, $user_name, $password, $db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Error: could not connect to database.  Please try again later.';
    exit ;
}

mysqli_select_db($db, $db_name) or die("could not connect");

$commandType = 'unknown';
$feedURL="";
if (isset($_GET['cmd'])) {
    $commandType = trim($_GET['cmd']);
    $commandType = strtolower($commandType);
}
if ($commandType == 'staff') {

    if (isset($_GET['fname']) && isset($_GET['lname'])) {

        $fname = trim($_GET['fname']);
        $fname = strtolower($fname);
        $lname = trim($_GET['lname']);
        $lname = strtolower($lname);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE fname like '" . $fname . "%' AND '" . $lname . "%'";

    } else if (isset($_GET['lname'])) {
        $commandType = trim($_GET['cmd']);
        $commandType = strtolower($commandType);
        $lname = trim($_GET['lname']);
        $lname = strtolower($lname);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE lname like '" . $lname . "%'";

    } else if (isset($_GET['fname'])) {
        $commandType = trim($_GET['cmd']);
        $commandType = strtolower($commandType);
        $lname = trim($_GET['fname']);
        $lname = strtolower($fname);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM staff WHERE lname like '" . $fname . "%'";
    } else {
        $commandType = trim($_GET['cmd']);
        $commandType = strtolower($commandType);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $commandType;
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {

        echo '{"Data":[';

        $first = true;
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

            if ($first) {
                $first = false;
            } else {
                echo ',';
            }
            echo json_encode($row);
        }
        echo ']}';
    } else {
        echo '[]';
    }
} else if ($commandType == 'event') {
    if (isset($_GET['current']) && isset($_GET['future'])) {
        $current = $_GET['current'];
        $current = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
        $currentDate = date("Y-m-d", $current);

        $future = $_GET['future'];
        $future = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d") + 7, date("Y"));
        $futureDate = date("Y-m-d", $future);
        $userid = 'michael.herrera1977%40gmail.com';
        $magicWord = '200f9cbc38a87ae4f65051f26d19e5a4';
        $feedURL = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/$userid/private-$magicWord/basic?start-min=$currentDate&start-max=$futureDate";

    } else if (isset($_GET['current'])) {
        $current = $_GET['current'];
        $current = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));
        $currentDate = date("Y-m-d", $current);
        $userid = 'michael.herrera1977%40gmail.com';
        $magicWord = '200f9cbc38a87ae4f65051f26d19e5a4';
        $feedURL = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/$userid/private-$magicWord/basic?start-min=$currentDate";

    } else if (isset($_GET['future'])) {
        $future = $_GET['future'];
        $future = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d") + 7, date("Y"));
        $futureDate = date("Y-m-d", $future);
        $userid = 'michael.herrera1977%40gmail.com';
        $magicWord = '200f9cbc38a87ae4f65051f26d19e5a4';
        $feedURL = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/$userid/private-$magicWord/basic?start-max=$futureDate";
    }

    // read feed into SimpleXML object
    $xmlSimple = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

    //gets info based on CMD this will be pulled up if CMD = events
    //if(isset($_GET['events']))

    //put each title and content from each date into the array
    foreach ($xmlSimple->entry as $entry) {
        $title = stripslashes($entry -> title);
        $content = stripslashes($entry -> content);
        $eventsArray[] = array('Title' => $title, 'content' => $content);

    }
    //clean up json string for easy cheesy use and to get the when, where and event seperated
    $json = json_encode($eventsArray);
    $json = str_replace('"content":', '', $json);
    $json = str_replace('\n', '', $json);
    $json = str_replace('"When:', '"When":"', $json);
    $json = str_replace('Where:', '","Where":"', $json);
    $json = str_replace('Event Status: confirmed', '', $json);
    $json = str_replace('Event Description:', '","Event Description":"', $json);
    $json = preg_replace('/\s+/', '%20', $json);

    echo $json;
}
?>
```

There was an html file that was included with this as well,

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>dbphp</title>
        <meta name="author" content="Michael" />
        <!-- Date: 2012-05-03 -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="dbphp.php" method="get" >
            <!--<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="staff">
            <input type="hidden" name="fname" value="m">
            <input type="hidden" name="lname" value="j"/><br />-->
            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="event">
            <input type="hidden" name="current" value="5/10/2012">
            <input type="hidden" name="future" value="5/15/2012"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enter staff member" />

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

I really wish I could just meet up with the Author but i doesn't seem to want to work out.

Any help you all could provide would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just some general info, but `SELECT *` is bad behaviour. Only select values you really need, this also speeds up the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a PHP-only question, by the looks of things. The API appears to use `?` arguments at the end of the PHP file, so we have:

1. `dbphp.php?cmd=staff&lname=<last_name>&fname=<first_name>`

   - Look up a user in the `staff` table.
2. `dbphp.php?cmd=<table_name>`

   - Get everything out of the `table_name` table. Eeek!
3. `dbphp.php?cmd=event?current=<date>&future=<date>`

   - Look up michael.herrera1977's Google calendar. The json return value gets horrendously clobbered before returning it

The database lives on the same server that the PHP is on, `localhost`. To parse the output, there are the standard `JSONArray` and `JSONObject` classes to help you out. I'd also delete all the `str_replace` and `preg_replace` code as they might make the JSON output from Google invalid.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if I would have to edit it. So how would the user, once we have this live, access the database if it is on a server outside of the app itself?

Comment: The PHP and the MySQL server will be on your server device, so the problem becomes "How to I query a server from Android and parse the JSON reply?" Here is [a sample project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php), and you would use `p.setParameter("cmd", "staff"); p.setParameter("fname", "Ken");` to look up staff named Ken. (Also note, there's a bug in the PHP above `"SELECT * FROM staff WHERE lname like '" . $fname . "%'"`)

Comment: Thanks! That link is really helpful and your input on the PHP page was very much needed.